Redistribute column values within groups based on age & relationship criteria
Problem:
I have a dataframe of individuals, specifying household groups, relationships between household members, and individual ages, and household income.
Currently total household income hy040g:hy050gis entered in full for each individual in the household, however this needs to be redistributed to individuals according to different rules (e.g. where there are multiple married couples in a house).
Example Dataframe
   household age        r01        r02     r03         r04 hy040g hy060g hy070g hy080g hy090g hy110g hy050g
1          1  40       <NA>     spouse  parent      parent     40     20     30      0     60    100    120
2          1  38     spouse       <NA>  parent      parent     40     20     30      0     60    100    120
3          1  17      child      child    <NA>     sibling     40     20     30      0     60    100    120
4          1   9      child      child sibling        <NA>     40     20     30      0     60    100    120
5          2  68       <NA>     spouse  parent grandparent    100     10     15     80     25     80     70
6          2  74     spouse       <NA>  parent grandparent    100     10     15     80     25     80     70
7          2  34      child      child    <NA>      parent    100     10     15     80     25     80     70
8          2   2 grandchild grandchild   child        <NA>    100     10     15     80     25     80     70
9          3  89       <NA>     parent    <NA>        <NA>      0      0     30     50      0      0      0
10         3  54      child       <NA>    <NA>        <NA>      0      0     30     50      0      0      0
11         4  35       <NA>       <NA>    <NA>        <NA>     30     40      0      0      0     25     10

Code to reproduce
df <- data.frame(household = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3, 2), 4),
                 age = c(40,38,17,9,68,74,34,2,89,54,35),
                 r01 = c(NA, "spouse", "child", "child", NA, "spouse", "child", "grandchild", NA, "child", NA),
                 r02 = c("spouse", NA, "child", "child", "spouse", NA, "child", "grandchild", "parent", NA, NA),
                 r03 = c("parent", "parent", NA, "sibling", "parent", "parent", NA, "child", rep(NA,3)),
                 r04 = c(rep("parent",2), "sibling", NA, rep("grandparent", 2), "parent", rep(NA,4)),
                 hy040g = c(rep(40,4), rep(100,4), 0, 0, 30),
                 hy060g = c(rep(20,4), rep(10,4), 0, 0, 40),
                 hy070g = c(rep(30,4), rep(15,4), 30, 30, 0),
                 hy080g = c(rep(0,4), rep(80,4), 50, 50, 0),
                 hy090g = c(rep(60,4), rep(25,4), rep(0,3)),
                 hy110g = c(rep(100,4), rep(80,4), 0, 0, 25),
                 hy050g = c(rep(120,4), rep(70,4), 0, 0, 10))

Rules:
hy040g:hy090g distributed (i) to the oldest person in household in full if they are unmarried, or (ii) evenly to the oldest person and their spouse if married.
hy110g distributed evenly among all household members aged under 17 (or evenly to every household member if nobody is aged under 17)
For hy050g distributed evenly among all household members aged under 19 (of evenly to every household member is nobody is aged under 19)
Desired Output
   household age        r01        r02     r03         r04 hy040g.d hy060g.d hy070g.d hy080g.d hy090g.d hy110g.d hy050g.d
1          1  40       <NA>     spouse  parent      parent       20       10     15.0        0     30.0        0        0
2          1  38     spouse       <NA>  parent      parent       20       10     15.0        0     30.0        0        0
3          1  17      child      child    <NA>     sibling        0        0      0.0        0      0.0        0       60
4          1   9      child      child sibling        <NA>        0        0      0.0        0      0.0      100       60
5          2  68       <NA>     spouse  parent grandparent       50        5      7.5       40     12.5        0        0
6          2  74     spouse       <NA>  parent grandparent       50        5      7.5       40     12.5        0        0
7          2  34      child      child    <NA>      parent        0        0      0.0        0      0.0        0        0
8          2   2 grandchild grandchild   child        <NA>        0        0      0.0        0      0.0       80       70
9          3  89       <NA>     parent    <NA>        <NA>        0        0     30.0       50      0.0        0        0
10         3  54      child       <NA>    <NA>        <NA>        0        0      0.0        0      0.0        0        0
11         4  35       <NA>       <NA>    <NA>        <NA>       30       40      0.0        0      0.0       25       10

Approach:
So far I have tried a primarily dplyr approach, creating helper columns (below) then moving to ifselse. I'm running into issues here (e.g. where there are multiple married couples within a household), and I think there might be a more elegant way of mapping these across...
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(married = as.numeric(length(na.omit(match(c(r01, r02, r03, r04), "spouse")))) > 0,
         u19 = age > 19,
         u17 = age > 17) %>%
  group_by(household) %>%
  mutate(oldest = +(age == max(age)))


Try this
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  nest(.by = household, .key = "data") %>% 
  mutate(data = map(
    data,
    ~mutate(.x,
            oldest = (age == max(age)),
            spouse_oldest = str_detect(string = str_glue("r0{which(oldest)}") %>% get(), 
                                       pattern = "spouse"),
            across(hy040g:hy090g, ~ifelse(oldest|spouse_oldest,
                                         .x/sum(c(oldest, spouse_oldest), na.rm =TRUE),
                                         0),
                   .names = "{.col}.d"),
            # hy110g
            hy110g.d = case_when(
              sum(age < 17)!=0 ~ ifelse(age < 17, hy110g / sum(age< 17), 0),
              TRUE ~ hy110g / n()
            ),
            # hy050g
            hy050.d = case_when(
              sum(age < 19)!=0 ~ ifelse(age < 19, hy050g / sum(age < 19), 0),
              TRUE ~ hy050g / n()
            ))
  )) %>%
  unnest(data) %>% 
  select(household:r04, ends_with(".d"))


thanks - this solution works well with my example data. Unfortunately the actual environment I am working is is protected and uses and old version of purrr (0.3.4) and the solution is throwing up errors (Caused by error in purrr:::stop_bad_type())

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This should get the job done too
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  group_by(household) %>% 
  mutate(oldest = (age == max(age)),
         spouse_oldest = str_detect(string = str_glue("r0{which(oldest)}") %>% get(), 
                                    pattern = "spouse"),
         across(hy040g:hy090g, ~ifelse(oldest|spouse_oldest,
                                       .x/sum(c(oldest, spouse_oldest), na.rm =TRUE),
                                       0),
                .names = "{.col}.d"),
         # hy110g
         hy110g.d = case_when(
           sum(age < 17)!=0 ~ ifelse(age < 17, hy110g / sum(age< 17), 0),
           TRUE ~ hy110g / n()
         ),
         # hy050g
         hy050.d = case_when(
           sum(age < 19)!=0 ~ ifelse(age < 19, hy050g / sum(age < 19), 0),
           TRUE ~ hy050g / n()
         )) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(household:r04, ends_with(".d"))

